# Is there a way to specify multiple public directories with static assets with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, webpack, frontend

I have Vue project that has standard webpack configuration generated from the Vue CLI. This gives project directory structure such as:

```
public\
  css\
  images\
  index.html
src\
tests\
package.json
etc...
```

So the default static assets directory is `public\` in the root of the project dir. Now I want to specify another static directory (which will be located somewhere in the `src\`) such that content of these two dirs is merged on build. In case of file conflicts, the file from `src\` should overwrite the one in `public\`.

How can I do this with webpack?

The reason I need this is because I want to make separate builds for different customer. Each customer will have it's own specific assets and components which I plan to put somewhere in `src\`. Eg:

```
public\             // shared static assets
src\
   components\      // shared stuff for all customers
   store\
   ...etc        

   customer1\       // customer1 specific stuff below this level
      public\       // merge these with shared static assets and overwrite if necessary
      components\
      store\
      index.js

   customer2\       // customer2 specific stuff below this level
      public\
      components\
      store\
      index.js
```

So then when I run `npm run build --customer=customer1` I want to get only shared + customer1 stuff in the bundle. I almost solved this for customer's components, store and other non-static stuff via [webpack alias config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) and I am wondering how can I do it for static assets in the `public` directory?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how Webpack works. When you compile your App, the first thing Webpack does is to scan your code and build a dependency tree. In reality, a dependency can be many things, but think of them as your "imported files".

The scan starts at your entry point, generally `src/index.js` and it proceeds recursively from there. What I want to be clear with this is that only "explicit" dependencies are bundled, anything else will be ignored. In other words, if you don't import something and have a specific loader for that, that asset will not be bundled.

So again, Webpack does not scan your `src` directory, but traverses your App from its entry point.

Also consider that with a good setup (like the one included with Create React App) almost every asset will be converted into a JS module and merged into chunks with a specific naming convention to allow cache invalidation. This is to say that there is little probability there will be name collisions.

Given your case, I would very, very, very, very highly recommend you to have a different repository for each different client. If you need to reuse components, author a library. If you need to reuse assets, optimize them and host them on a CDN. I would expect security, maintainability and scalability problems with your approach.

Finally, if you insist, one viable approach would be to have a custom plugin attached to those "static" directories inside your `src` directory (you can search around if there is already one available, if not, see custom plugins in Webpack documentation, it is not that straightforward though). That plugin would basically change the path of the imported file based on an environment variable or a passed option.

Please let me know if I am overlooking something, but I really think you should separate the projects, even if the "base" is the same.

As a final note: Your approach would must likely break any static analysis (Forget about TypeScript, Flow, JSDocs, IDE auto-completion and hinting, etc.). You would be also breaking modular programming paradigm. This especially applies to components. With other media assets like images there would be less constraints, but still encounter issues. How would your app run in dev mode? At best you'll encounter performance problems. You can break HMR (Hot Module Replacement), app tests... I'll stop here.

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed answer and effort but I have some experience and know how webpack works and builds graph tree. I already managed to create independent builds for each customer based on the project structure I shown above and the env variable which can be taken from cmd line and turned into customer subdirectory. Then I reference it like `import customerApi from '#customer#'` where `#customer#` is specified via webpack `alias` config.  So that is all fine, and works with dev and prod builds, HMR etc... no worries about that. I just now need to figure out this about static assets.

Comment: @mlst and don't you have problems with type checking, auto-completion, etc.? However, for the other issues I was referring to the idea of creating a plugin to replace paths.

Comment: @mlst what I don't understand now is why don't you do the same for those static assets? You can import almost everything when using Webpack (media files, JSON files, documents, etc.), what is the problem?

Comment: Static assets are treated differently than other stuff which are converted via plugins. Statics are not processed by webpack (afaik) and they are just used as-is from the web app. I could probably create a plugin that would merge customer specific static assets with shared ones but I was wondering is this already implemented via some configuration so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @mlst See [Asset Management](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/) in the official docs. Static assets that are explicitly imported into your code (exactly as you do with your React components) are treated exactly as any other imported resource. Maybe different loaders/plugins will be involved, but the base logic is the same. So you can use aliases for static assets too. Strictly speaking, if there is no data fetched from a server, everything in your frontend is "static", not just images and similar stuff.

Comment: @mlst As an example, you could do `import myImage from '../#customer#/img/my-image.jpg';` or `import myImage from '../#customer#/img/my-image.svg';` and those assets will be processed and bundled. Depending on used loaders, they will be transformed differently. For example, JPEG images can be just copied or converted into a Base64 string, SVG can be embedded in JS as React objects, assets can be compressed, minified, etc.

Comment: @mlst in fact, the `public` directory has always been an escape hatch and it is not recommended to use it for any asset. Especially today that there are loaders for everything. Am I missing something?